# Get autocompletion of script names in $PATH

Tags: autocompletion

I would like to know how I could set up script names auto completion in vim ?

For example let's say I have `myscript.sh` in `~/bin` and `~/bin` is in my $PATH, I would like to type `mys` in vim and get auto completion.
I think it should be possible with `CTRL-X CTRL-U` or `CTRL-X CTRL-O` but not sure how.

Note: I've already an Omni completion set up by let &runtimepath pointing to a vim program directory.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You shouldn’t need to change runtimepath to enable or setup an omni completion, so I’m not sure I follow that

Comment: Sorry maybe I am not clear enough, I am using a program that enables vim auto completion and the doc states to add: `:let &runtimepath.=','.$MYPROGRAM_VIMPATH` and `:set completeopt=longest,menuone` in .vimrc to activate auto completion. I just wanted to notice this such that I do not break this auto completion.

Comment: Interesting... I don’t think it’s relevant, but I wonder if you could share a link to the program? Most plugins don’t require such a manual manipulation of rtp.

Comment: Sure here the doc: https://www.plumed.org/doc-v2.5/user-doc/html/_vim_syntax.html

Comment: That doc doesn't really follow vim best practice. You could instead put the syntax file in `~/.vim/after/syntax/plumed.vim` and then write an ftdetect to set the filetype (thereby setting the syntax) for the appropriate files. This is what most language plugins do, except they don't use after (and, however you install your plugins, they get automatically put on the runtimepath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to write a custom completer:

```
function ShellCmd(findstart, base) abort
  if a:findstart
    " ... some logic here to find the start of a word
    " ... example near `:help E839`
  else
    return split($PATH, ':')
          \ ->map({_,v -> glob(v.'/*', v:true, v:true, v:true)})
          \ ->flatten()
          \ ->map({_,v -> fnamemodify(v, ':t')})
          \ ->filter({_,v -> v =~# a:base})
  endif
endfunction
```

If you only want to match commands that start with `a:base`, you should change the last filter to `v =~# '^'.a:base`.

Assign this to `completefunc` and use `<C-x><C-u>`.

---

When writing a custom command, you can use `-complete=shellcmd`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this does the trick ! However I am not sure I got your comments: "If you only want to match commands that start with a:base, you should change the last filter to v =~# '^'.a:base" and "When writing a custom command, you can use -complete=shellcmd". I am at a basic level on vim, could you give examples maybe ?

Comment: @jeremy help is your friend; in this case, `:help pattern` for the first and `:help command-complete` for the second. For the first, the matching is currently unanchored, so completions for « vim » will return all shell executables in path that contain vim—even those that dont start with vim! This may or may not be want you want, so you can anchor the start of the match if you need to. The custom command piece isn’t really relevant to you, but when defining a command (`:help :command`) you can give it your own completion as well.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks once more !